# jQuery - determine if input element is textbox or select list

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How would I determine whether the element returned by an :input filter in jQuery is a textbox or select list?

I want to have a different behavior for each ( textbox returns text value, select returns both key and text)

Example setup:

```
<div id="InputBody">
<div class="box">
    <span id="StartDate">
        <input type="text" id="control1">
    </span>
    <span id="Result">
        <input type="text" id="control2">
    </span>
    <span id="SelectList">
        <select>
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <span id="StartDate">
        <input type="text" id="control1">
    </span>
    <span id="Result">
        <input type="text" id="control2">
    </span>
    <span id="SelectList">
        <select>
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
    </span>
</div>
```

and then the script:

```
$('#InputBody')
    // find all div containers with class = "box"
    .find('.box')
    .each(function () {
        console.log("child: " + this.id);

        // find all spans within the div who have an id attribute set (represents controls we want to capture)
        $(this).find('span[id]')
        .each(function () {
            console.log("span: " + this.id);

            var ctrl = $(this).find(':input:visible:first');

            console.log(this.id + " = " + ctrl.val());
            console.log(this.id + " SelectedText = " + ctrl.find(':selected').text());

        });
```

Answer (score 186, accepted):

You could do this:

```
if( ctrl[0].nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'input' ) {
    // it was an input
}
```

or this, which is slower, but shorter and cleaner:

```
if( ctrl.is('input') ) {
    // it was an input
}
```

---

If you want to be more specific, you can test the type:

```
if( ctrl.is('input:text') ) {
    // it was an input
}
```

Comment: I had to add the jquery syntax $(element).is('input') to get it to work but all in all great.

Answer (score 30):

alternatively  you can retrieve DOM properties 
with `.prop`

here is sample code for select box

```
if( ctrl.prop('type') == 'select-one' ) { // for single select }

if( ctrl.prop('type') == 'select-multiple' ) { // for multi select }
```

for textbox

```
  if( ctrl.prop('type') == 'text' ) { // for text box }
```

Comment: This works like a charm with new jQuery function prop(). Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

If you just want to check the type, you can use jQuery's .is() function,

Like in my case I used below,

```
if($("#id").is("select")) {
 alert('Select'); 
else if($("#id").is("input")) {
 alert("input");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can determine if a form element is an input or a select with this code :

```
$('ElementSelector').prop('tagName').toLowerCase();
```