# Check if input is of type "text/number/email/etc"?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to check with Javascript (not jQuery) if the given input element is writable by the user using the keyboard.

I'd like to exclude checkboxes, radios, buttons, resets, submits, image and so on.

Is there a simple way to do it without list all the input types?

This is my current code now:

```
if (element.getAttribute === undefined) {
    return false;
}

var eTag  = element.tagName;
var eType = element.getAttribute('type');
var isTextInput = (eTag === 'INPUT' || eTag === 'TEXTAREA') && ( eType !== null || eType === 'text' || eType === 'password');
var isEnabledInput = element.disabled === false && element.readOnly === false;
var isContentEditable = ( element.contentEditable && element.contentEditable === true );

// stop for enabled text inputs, selects and contentEditable areas
return (isTextInput && isEnabledInput) || eType === 'SELECT' || isContentEditable;
```

Logically the `&& ( eType !== null || eType === 'text' || eType === 'password');` is not enough to check them all.

Comment: This seems to be the jquery answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108337/jquery-determine-if-input-element-is-textbox-or-select-list

Comment: @djechlin no with that code you just test if the element is an input (the second example tests if is a input of `type = text`). It will return `false` if the input is of type `number`

Comment: Problem is "text" is too narrow and "input" is too broad?

Comment: I wonder why all these downvotes... It's a legitimate question.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as an answer because fixes the problem, but it's not strictly what I'm asking for.

I'm still waiting for a cleaner solution.

```
var notTextual = [
    'button',
    'checkbox',
    'hidden',
    'image',
    'radio',
    'reset',
    'submit'
];

if (element.getAttribute === undefined) {
    return false;
}

var eTag  = element.tagName;
var eType = element.getAttribute('type');
var isTextInput = (eTag === 'INPUT' || eTag === 'TEXTAREA') && !notTextual.contains(eType);
var isEnabledInput = element.disabled === false && element.readOnly === false;
var isContentEditable = ( element. isContentEditable && element. isContentEditable === true );

// stop for enabled text inputs, selects and contentEditable areas
return (isTextInput && isEnabledInput) || eType === 'SELECT' || isContentEditable;
```

Comment: This is the most complete code for this problem I've seen so far.    `element.contentEditable` doesn't seem to be the right thing to call.  Instead it should be `element.isContentEditable`.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna call a function depending on the type of input, create an array with the wished types of input, another with the types function and do a loop.

```
function GetInputType(e){ // e = element
   var Types=[
      "text",
      "password"
   ],
   Attr=e.getAttribute("type"),
   Actions=[
      function(){alert("It's text.")},
      function(){alert("It's password.")}
   ],
   Call=function(){alert("Unknown type.")};
   for(var i=0,l=Types.length;i<l;i++){
      !function(i){
         if(Attr==Types[i])
            Call=Actions[i];
         else break
      }(i)
   }
   Call()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I *think* you're going to need to write something yourself. You're asking for more specific business logic than you think.

- `text` is text.
- `number` is text but the input must be 0-9, and decimal.
- `password` is text-input, black circles or similar shown on screen.
- Radio buttons are certainly keyboard-inputtable. Text won't display, but that's also true for `password`. Also the input is essentially "yes" or "no," but that's just a restriction on what keyboard inputs do, just like `number` is a restriction on what keyboard inputs do.

So you want something like...

- the keyboard can input at least some of the time...
- and text must display on screen unless it's a password...
- and more input should be accepted than just a "space" or "enter" as in radio button or checkbox

That's not a standard HTML modifier, or standard jQuery, or anything. That's *your own business logic.*

I know this is a non-answer but I think there's good reason to believe you won't find what you're looking for out-of-the-box somewhere. It depends on your own application's logic, exactly what you mean by "text."

Comment: well actually I just need to know if the input displays a field where the user can insert characters or not...

Comment: @FezVrasta does `date` count?

Comment: I don't think so, date is a text input on not supported browser, and on supported browsers there's still a text input + widget

Comment: @FezVrasta you mean it *does* count? since there's text input either way

Comment: I mean, it's writable

Comment: @FezVrasta what about `time`? You enter text, but not intuitively and backspace doesn't work.

Comment: @FezVrasta there's also `color`. On Chrome you open the picker *then* enter text.