# javascript : check if <input> is input-field

Tags: javascript, html

HTML5 comes with a lot of new types for

```
<input />
```

How can I detect if an input field is "a text field" (date, time, email, text, everything)

I do not want to write `input[type='text'],input[type='xxx']` ...

Comment: Please only tag appropriately. This question has nothing to do with [tag:object], [tag:cross-browser], [tag:inspector], or [tag:properties]. *(Not my downvote)*

Comment: object: The solution could be that a property in the INPUT-object lead to the fieldtype.

Comment: cross-browser: other browsers have other properties for html elements i guess..

Comment: By that measure, almost all questions would be tagged [tag:object]. Which would be unhelpful to put it mildly.

Comment: When you say 'text' inputs; what do you mean, exactly? That they contain text in the input element?

Comment: Also I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923112/check-if-input-is-of-type-text-number-email-etc

Answer (score 1):

You can use [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) to get whatever attribute you want (this includes `type`)

```js
var input = document.getElementById('myinput');
var inputTYpe = input.getAttribute('type');
var isText = inputTYpe === 'text' || inputTYpe === '';

console.log('type is ', input.getAttribute('type'), ' is text = ', isText)
```

```html
<input type="hey" id="myinput" />
```

Comment: Code dumps are not *useful* answers. Say what you did, and why.

Answer (score 1):

> CSS3 comes with a lot of new types for `<input />`

HTML5, not CSS3.

> I do not want to write `input[type='text'],input[type='xxx']`

Unfortunately, I don't think you get a choice. But since the vast majority of them are text-like, you probably want to just call out the ones that aren't (like `range`, `checkbox`, `radio`, `file`, `submit`, `image`, `reset`, `button` — only one of which is new with HTML5).

Where possible, you'll want to isolate that to a single spot. You've mentioned CSS, which may make it difficult, but for instance if you were doing this in JavaScript, you'd want a single reusable function so you could update it as necessary.

Comment: Just make sure you define one central function / list, so you can update that at just one point if it changes someday.

Comment: @Unknown - Very good point, I should have included that. (Now I have.)

Answer (score 0):

```
function unameit(el) {
  var words=['button','checkbox','hidden','image','radio','range','reset','submit'],tp=el.type.toLowerCase();
  return words.indexOf(tp)<0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to differenciate between tags, you can check the tag by using

```
elementTag.tagName
```

For example, if you have a Input, you will get the text "INPUT"

And if you want to know what kind of imput is being used, you can check by looking at the attribute

```
elementTag.type
```